# If $\overrightarrow{a}, \overrightarrow{b}, \overrightarrow{c} \in D^3$ it is proved that a + b + c = 0 => a x b = b x c = c x a

Tags: vectors

If $\overrightarrow{a}, \overrightarrow{b}, \overrightarrow{c} \in D^3$ it is proved that $ \overrightarrow{a} + \overrightarrow{b} + \overrightarrow{c} = 0 \Rightarrow  \overrightarrow{a} \times \overrightarrow{b} = \overrightarrow{b} \times \overrightarrow{c} = \overrightarrow{c} \times \overrightarrow{a} $

So taking the first part with cross product of $\overrightarrow{a}$ and $\overrightarrow{b}$ respectively

$$
\left\{\begin{array}{test}
\overrightarrow{a} \times ( \overrightarrow{a} + \overrightarrow{b} + \overrightarrow{c} ) = 0 \\
\overrightarrow{b} \times ( \overrightarrow{a} + \overrightarrow{b} + \overrightarrow{c} ) = 0
\end{array}\right\} \Rightarrow \overrightarrow{a} \times \overrightarrow{b} = \overrightarrow{b} \times \overrightarrow{c} = \overrightarrow{c} \times \overrightarrow{a}
$$

Is this way of thinking right, or the two equations have infinite solutions? I mean, no matter which vector we multiply with $( \overrightarrow{a} + \overrightarrow{b} + \overrightarrow{c} )$ it's going to be zero anyway.
So is this a gap in our reasoning?

Comment: You might include a bit more details, e.g. what is the value of $\overrightarrow{a} \times\overrightarrow{a}$ and how do you use that? Just the implication arrow seems a bit too sketchy, but it is correct, assuming the reader would correctly guess the details that you meant but did not include.

Comment: a, b, c are vectors in three dimensional space. I thought it was understood in the beginning. Their values are unknown.
It is an actual exercise that requests to prove that a + b + c = 0 => a x b = b x c = c x a

Comment: that is fine, but how exactly do you get $\overrightarrow{a} \times \overrightarrow{b} = \overrightarrow{c} \times \overrightarrow{a}$, for example? I think you are using that $\overrightarrow{a} \times\overrightarrow{a}=\overrightarrow{0}$ and that $\overrightarrow{a} \times \overrightarrow{c} = -\overrightarrow{c} \times \overrightarrow{a}$ but you could include the details of the computation, a sequence of equalities that you transform, to get what you need at the end.

Comment: From the two equations in the brackets. The (a+b+c) parts are the same, so it has to be a = b and subsequently b = c and c = a if you take c x (a + b + c) = 0.

Comment: no, it doesn't have to be a=b and b=c, and c=a.

Comment: Why do some of the title in MathJax but not the rest?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks from the comments that you did not understand the details
that are missing from your proof, so here is a start.

$\overrightarrow{a} \times ( \overrightarrow{a} + \overrightarrow{b} + \overrightarrow{c} ) = \overrightarrow0$, hence 
$\overrightarrow{a} \times \overrightarrow{a} + \overrightarrow{a} \times \overrightarrow{b} + \overrightarrow{a} \times \overrightarrow{c}  = \overrightarrow0$.
Use that $\overrightarrow{a} \times \overrightarrow{a}=\overrightarrow0$, and that $\overrightarrow{a} \times \overrightarrow{c}=
-\overrightarrow{c} \times \overrightarrow{a}$ to obtain
$\overrightarrow{a} \times \overrightarrow{b} - \overrightarrow{c} \times \overrightarrow{a}  = \overrightarrow0$, and finally 
$\overrightarrow{a} \times \overrightarrow{b} = \overrightarrow{c} \times \overrightarrow{a} 
$.
Then do a similar argument at least once more.

Comment: Sorry, I'm trying to understand: how come a x a = 0?

Comment: that is one of the properties of vector (also called cross) product, I assume you study these properties, perhaps you need to review them. What do you know about cross product so far, how did your book/teacher define it, what properties does it obey, that you know? Did you define them in terms of certain areas, or in terms of certain matrices and their determinants (or in some other way)? In terms of areas a x a represents the area of a degenerate parallelogram (all sides contained in one single line) and the area is $0$.

Comment: Is it because |a x a| = |a| |a| sin(a,a)  where sin(a,a) = 0 right? I missed that property, it wasn't in teacher's notes. Thanks!

Comment: yes, you could use that the angle between $\overrightarrow{a}$ and $\overrightarrow{a}$ is $0$, thus $\sin(\overrightarrow{a},\overrightarrow{a})=\sin(0)=0$. Welcome to MSE !

Comment: Yes the properties of cross product results from geometrical represantation, the matrices stuff is another course.
So the sin(a,a) applies to 3 dimensions as well right?

Comment: Yes, it applies to three dimensions, but it remains, in essence, a two-dimensional thing. In general, if you have two vectors a,b in three-dimensional space, and they "start at the same point" and form an angle, then there is a plane p that contains these two vectors, so you could use what you know about angles between lines and vectors in a plane, even if the plane p in turn sits in three dimensional space.

Answer (score 0):

It's the right way of thinking. $\vec a+\vec b+\vec c=0$ can be understood geometrically as that the three vectors are coplanar. in that case, the cross product is a vector perpendicular to this plane, so at least $\vec a \times \vec b$, $ \vec b \times \vec c$, $\vec c \times \vec a$ point in the same direction. The magnitude of $\vec a \times \vec b$ is the area of parralelogram with sides $\vec a$ and $\vec b$. You have a similar interpretation for the other cross products. If $\vec c=-(\vec a+\vec b)$, you can also prove geometrically that the three areas are equal.

In conclusion, yes, you can multiply any vector with $\vec a+\vec b+\vec c$ and you still get $0$, but in general it's just a meaningless statement.